# Display the entire string if a partial match is found in a webpage using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, webrequest

I managed to extract what I wanted in the snippet below however, I think its problematic. I need help in returning the entire string based on the partial match.

```
import requests
url = "https://bscscan.com/address/0x88c20beda907dbc60c56b71b102a133c1b29b053#code"
queries = ["twitter", "www.", "https://t.me"]

r = requests.get(url)
for q in queries:
    q = q.lower()
    if q in r.text.lower():
        if q.startswith(tuple(queries)):
            print("Found ", q)
        else:
            print("Not Found ", q)
```

Current Output:

```
Found  www.
Found  https://t.me
```

Wanted Output:  #-- return the whole string

```
Found - www.shibuttinu.com
Found - https://t.me/Shibuttinu
Not Found - twitter
```

Comment: How do you define "the whole string"?

Comment: My partial string is www. my whole string is www.www.shibuttinu.com and if its t.me as my partial string, the whole string will be https://t.me/Shibuttinu

Comment: `if q.startswith(tuple(queries)` will always be true since q is items form queries so there for q will always start with one of the items from queries. this is a pointless check as will always be true. this is not checking against any of the response data.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using regular expressions to define the whole string you want to return.

Comment: Or maybe you should be using a web scraping library like Beautiful Soup to extract the specific information you want from the web page, and checking whether it starts with any of those strings.

Comment: How is Python supposed to know what "the whole string" is?  You have to TEACH it how to know that.  Are these of a tag?  Can it look for a "<" terminator?  Do you see what I mean?  Python doesn't know what you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a regular expression with your given `queries`. The following example assumes your whole strings are terminated by quotes a space or a newline (which might not always be the case?)

```
import requests
import re

url = "https://bscscan.com/address/0x88c20beda907dbc60c56b71b102a133c1b29b053#code"
r = requests.get(url)

queries = ["twitter", "www.", "https://t.me"]
re_queries = '|'.join(re.escape(q) for q in queries)
valid_url = "[a-z0-9:/?\-=&.]"
re_query = rf"['\" ]({valid_url}*?({re_queries}){valid_url}*?)['\"\n]"

for match in re.finditer(re_query, r.text, re.I):
    print(match.groups()[0])
```

This would return whole strings as:

```
twitter:card
twitter:title
twitter:description
twitter:site
twitter:image
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-46998878-23
www.shibuttinu.com
https://t.me/shibuttinu
https://www.binance.org/en/smartChain
https://twitter.com/BscScan
Twitter
```

What this is trying to do is locate all of your queries, but only if they proceeded with certain valid characters and also only if they are enclosed in quotes or a space. The regular expression syntax allows these restrictions to be defined. The use of the `re.I` flag allows these tests to be case insensitive (so removing the need to lowercase the text).